# Does the free shipping normally method remove all others?

Tags: shipping, ee-1.13

If free shipping is available, all other methods disappear in my shop.

Is this standard functionality (otherwise I might have to search for a custom modification)?

If it is standard, where in the code does that happen? The goal is to have some shipping methods still appear, even if free shipping is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a standard functionality.
Free shipping should appear along with other methods.
Maybe you have a minimum order value (0.01 or something like that) set for your other shipping methods in order to be available.
Or maybe there is indeed some custom code, that removes all the other methods when free shipping is available.

Comment: Custom code. The .phtml it is :-(